# Statistical Comparison of Continuous Outcomes Across Groups with Identical Observations

Tags: mixed-model, anova, post-hoc, group-differences, generalized-estimating-equations

Cross Validated community,

I am working with a dataset of restaurants that have been classified by both Michelin and Rafaelo rating systems. Specifically, Michelin has categorized restaurants into A, B, and C classes, while Rafaelo has rated them as 1-star and 2-star. Given these classifications, I would like to compare the average prices across these groups:

- Michelin A
- Michelin B
- Michelin C
- Rafaelo 1-star
- Rafaelo 2-star

However, my challenge is that some restaurants may appear in multiple categories between the two rating systems, leading to overlapping observations. (When i thought them as dependent variables and conduct a generalized estimating equations or regression model, I got the error of "singular Hessian matrix", therefore i think they are not dependent but same, so there should be another way to statistically compare the average price among groups)

Here are my questions:

How should I statistically compare the average prices between these groups while accounting for the fact that the same restaurant may be rated by both Michelin and Rafaelo?

What statistical methods are recommended for analyzing data where some observations belong to multiple groups (non-parametric or parametric tests based on confronting the related assumptions)?

Any insights on post-hoc tests and multiple comparison corrections in this context would also be greatly appreciated.

I am seeking advice on the best practices for approaching this analysis and ensuring that the comparisons are valid despite the dataset's complexity.

P.S. To initially address this, I created two rows for each restaurant: one for its Rafaelo rating and another for its Michelin classification. I then attempted to use generalized estimating equations or a mixed model with the restaurant name as a random effect to account for clustering. However, I encountered a singular Hessian matrix error when using the average price as the outcome. This might be due to my treatment of the two observations of the same restaurant as dependent when they are, in fact, the same entity.

Comment: Can you post some data? I have a sense of how one might deal with this, but it would be easier if I had data to play with.

Comment: I'm struggling to imagine an applicable null hypothesis.  "When some cases belong to multiple groups, we would expect under the null hypothesis that group differences would be xxx large ...."